# How to convert string time to unix?

Tags: lua

I'm creating an administrating tool and I need to convert string type like that: '1y2m3d4h5mi6s' to unixtime (seconds) in Lua. How can I make this?

I expect the output of `StrToTime("1d")` to be `86400`.

Comment: Split your string with [lua pattern](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) and use `os.time` to create the seconds ([lua date and time](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)). If you need any further help, I'll write a code snippet.

Comment: @csaar Can you please write a code snippet? Because when I try `%dd` it goes to error. Or I didn't get it.

Comment: What does '2m' mean? Two months or two minutes?

Comment: 2m is a month, 5mi - minutes. Edited, sorry, didn't noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function StrToTime(time_as_string)
   local dt = {year = 2000, month = 1, day = 1, hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0}
   local time0 = os.time(dt)
   local units = {y="year", m="month", d="day", h="hour", mi="min", s="sec", w="7day"}
   for num, unit in time_as_string:gmatch"(%d+)(%a+)" do
      local factor, field = units[unit]:match"^(%d*)(%a+)$"
      dt[field] = dt[field] + tonumber(num) * (tonumber(factor) or 1)
   end
   return os.time(dt) - time0
end

print(StrToTime("1d"))      --  86400
print(StrToTime("1d1s"))    --  86401
print(StrToTime("1w1d1s"))  --  691201
print(StrToTime("1w1d"))    --  691200
```

Answer (score 2):

Code snippet converting your date string to seconds

```
local testDate = '2019y2m8d15h0mi42s'
local seconds = string.gsub(
  testDate,
  '(%d+)y(%d+)m(%d+)d(%d+)h(%d+)mi(%d+)s',
  function(y, mon, d, h, min, s)
    return os.time{
      year = tonumber(y),
      month = tonumber(mon),
      day = tonumber(d),
      hour = tonumber(h),
      min = tonumber(min),
      sec = tonumber(s)
    }
  end
)
print(seconds)
```

You can also write a local function, I think it's a bit better to read.

```
local function printTime(y, mon, d, h, min, s)
  local res = os.time{
    year = tonumber(y),
    month = tonumber(mon),
    day = tonumber(d),
    hour = tonumber(h),
    min = tonumber(min),
    sec = tonumber(s)
  }
  return res
end

local testDate = '2019y2m8d15h0mi42s'
local seconds = string.gsub(
  testDate,
  '(%d+)y(%d+)m(%d+)d(%d+)h(%d+)mi(%d+)s',
  printTime
)
print(seconds)
```

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that the string provided by the OP would never work because `os.time` needs a year of 1970 or greater

Comment: This solution requires a full string. It does not work for `1d` for instance.

Comment: Returns string if I give only day, week, year or a month.

Comment: Yes this is only a smart way to convert, if the string is well formed. In other cases I'll need a bit more thinking^^
@JackGlowIchhu do you have some examples for valid string inputs? Which response is expected if not?

Comment: Yes, I expect something like that: `1d` = `86400`, `1d1s` = `86401`, `1w1d1s` = `691201` or `1w1d` = `691200`, etc, etc.

Comment: Use the solution of Egor Skriptunoff